# Are there "points of no return" in Transistor?

Tags: transistor

In many games, there are points of no return; once I choose a certain path or open a certain door, I cannot return and take the other path/go back through the door, even if there are still enemies to fight, information to gather, or items to collect back there.

Generally, I don't mind this, but I hate it when games sneak them in without letting the player know. It forces me to guess what path advances the storyline, then carefully avoid that path until I know I've gotten everything before it.

Does Transistor have "points of no return" that could make me need to reload from a checkpoint if I accidentally progress the storyline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game is fairly linear and straight forward. As far as I know, there are no 'points of no return' in regards to major storyline options, although some of the enemy encounters and descriptions of locations and objects can be bypassed and become impossible to get to in that playthrough.